# send messages to friends facebook sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb.ui, facebook-friends, facebook-messages

I have implemented sending message to friends through api like below.

```
    function share(){
      FB.ui({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxx',
        method: 'send',
        to : ["xxxxxxxxx"],
        link : "https://www.facebook.com",
        name : "xxxxxxxxx",
        description : "message"
      });
    }
```

I am able to send message but the receiver gets the message as

"This attachment may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to share it with you."

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: what is the exact link you are trying to send?

Comment: I tried to test it with the one mentioned in the docs - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog'-    http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html'

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Comment: did you try another link? for example, google.com or any external website?

Comment: Yes tried google, facebook and all famous sites...